# How to show pad designators at any zoom in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium

Below the designators are clearly visible on the pads:

[image: designators visible]

But after barely zooming out they disappear:

[image: designators not visible]

Is there any way to keep them on at lower zoom magnification? I am wasting a lot of time zooming in to check they have correct designators.

Comment: I thought it's an optical illusion :(

Comment: Why would you want to? you wouldn't be able to see the pads... when zoomed out you would see only pad designators. I usually ctrl+click traces or cross probe to help me route or find things on schematics from the PCB

Comment: @VoltageSpike Of course, at low enough zoom magnification (zoomed out) the designators would be illegibly small (not sure why you assume the designators would eclipse the pad size); but the designators are disappearing long before this happens, forcing me to zoom in whenever I'd like to check them (there are many more than pictured in my question). Thanks for your suggestion, but there is no PCB to cross probe (yet).

Comment: Because when you zoom in, alitum keeps the text size the same (for the most part) relative to the zoom, if you were to zoom out the text would become larger than the pads. If you were to introduce a feature that could zoom out and keep the text size the same, the text would be larger than the pads and this would create issues. Because of this altium stops showing the text when you zoom out because you can't see it any more.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Again, you're assuming that there is some reason why the "feature" could not make the text scale down with the size of the pad. Of course, I don't expect the text to show for extremely low mag (zoomed way out), but it's disappearing unreasonably quickly as I zoom out.